# Extract data to string from json in bash

Tags: bash

How can I extract the ip address and the country and put them individual in a string without any quotes or any other characters which are present in the text by using the next command:

```
info_ip=`wget --tries=1 --timeout=10 -qO- http://ipinfo.io/?callback=callback; echo`
```

Now I'm looking to filter the data for ip and country

$ip = ?

$country = ?

`ipinfo.io` currently returns something like:

```
/**/ typeof callback === 'function' && callback({
  "ip": "198.51.100.123",
  "hostname": "host.example.com",
  "city": "Example City",
  "region": "Example Region",
  "country": "XY",
  "loc": "12.3456,-1.2345",
  "postal": "XXX",
  "org": "ASXXXX Example Organisation"
});
```

Comment: I couldn't not figure out how to do it in the end.

Comment: If you paste here the JSON output, we can answer the question, otherwise the answers will be only educated guesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach.

```
A=($(wget -t1 -T10 -qO- ipinfo.io/?callback=callback|awk -F\" '/ip|country/{print$4}'))
echo ${A[0]}
35.230.152.185
echo ${A[1]}
US
```

As Stéphane Chazelas pointed out, this would behave badly if "ip" or "country" seen elsewhere in the output.  A more robust solution:

```
A=($(wget -t1 -T10 -qO- ipinfo.io/?callback=callback|awk -F\" '$2~/^(ip|country)$/{print$4}'))
```

Comment: Less code, the most easy way I guess

Comment: That is quite brittle. It would fail if any of the fields contained "ip"  or "country" or ip appeared after country.

Comment: So the second version fix the fail problem?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
read -r ip country < <(
  wget --tries=1 --timeout=10 -qO- 'http://ipinfo.io/?callback=callback' |
     perl -MJSON -l -0777 -ne '
       if (/callback\((.*)\);$/s) {
          $j = from_json($1);
          print "$j->{ip} $j->{country}"
       }'
)
```

For a shell with builtin JSON support, see ksh93v (currently in beta):

```
ipinfo=${
  wget --tries=1 --timeout=10 -qO- 'http://ipinfo.io/?callback=callback'
} || exit
ipinfo=${ipinfo/%*"callback("@(*)");"/\1}
IFS= read -rm json j <<< $ipinfo
ip=${j.ip} country=${j.country}
```

Note that instead of that `?callback` query (btw, `?` is a shell wildcard so needs to be quoted), [you can also use](https://ipinfo.io/developers#json-response):

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' ipinfo.io/json
```

or:

```
wget --tries=1 --header='Accept: application/json' --timeout=10 -qO- http://ipinfo.io/json
```

Which you could pipe to `jq -r '.ip, .country'`:

```
{ read -r ip; read -r country; } < <(
  curl -H 'Accept: application/json' ipinfo.io/json |
  jq -r '.ip, .country'
)
```

Comment: Thank you but seems @steve has the most easiest way.

Comment: @JohnDoe, easier but less reliable. See also the edit for a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
info_ip=`wget --tries=1 --timeout=10 -qO- http://ipinfo.io/?callback=callback; echo`
IFS=$'\n'
IP_country=( $(awk -F'[:"]' '/ip/ || /country/{ print $5}' <<<"$info_ip") )
ip=${IP_country[0]}
country=${IP_country[1]}
echo $ip
echo $country
```

Comment: That is quite brittle. It would fail if any of the fields contained "ip" or "country" or if the ip or country contained ":" (like for IPv6 addresses) or wildcard characters (those ones causing a DoS vulnerability) or if ip appeared after country.